# Can I hookup a 6V battery to my PCB with LDO voltage regulator to power my ESP32?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, esp32

[image: An image of my power source circuit]

I have 4 AAA batteries in series (~6V) and I was thinking of connecting it to my circuit to power the ESP32 using a 1x2 pin header.

I put a voltage regulator there which has a max current output of 1A and a set voltage output of 3.3V. Here’s an image of its typical application from datasheet:
[image: Typical application]

My question is:

1. Since the ESP32 has a voltage regulator of its own, will this cause any unintended consequences as theres 2 different voltage regulators involved before power reaches the ESP32? Anything to take note of when interfacing with 2 voltage regulators?
2. In the typical application image, they used a 10uF capacitor for 5.3V. Do I have to change its value since my power source is 6V?
3. To reduce power consumption, is buck converter a more viable solution?

Thats all I have to ask as of now. I hope yall can point out any additional flaws in my circuit as well. My first time asking here

Comment: You can't power the built in regulator with 6v directly?

Comment: "Since the ESP32 has a voltage regulator of its own" - which ESP32 chip or module are you talking about? Or is it an ESP32 devboard like the NodeMCU? If it's a devboard, just feed the 6V straight to the onboard regulator. If it's an ESP32 module, we need to know which one in order to be able to tell you whether you need an external LDO.

Comment: It is a NodeMCU devboard that I am using. And as to why I dont plug the battery straight to the ESP32, the GPIO pin of the ESP32 can only output a max of 40mA of current and I dont believe that is sufficient for the other components in the circuit. I will have to power eight RGB LEDs, four 7 segment displays and a few ICs. So thats why I believe it needs to get power from the battery directly.